# What are some shortcomings of the board design?

Tags: design

What parts of the board could cause electronics professionals to think it was constructed poorly, quickly, or unprofessionally? Is it simply soldering, a lack of clean trimming, or placement of the components themselves?

Comment: me trying to recover from [this failed attempt](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/582/271)

Comment: Sorry but this question has the same problems as your previous one.

Comment: What's your aim here? Are you interested in the board design, or are you trying to prove a point? The quality/soldering/trimming/placement appears fine to me. Considering the budget, features, and that it's the first major release, I'm very impressed.

Comment: @Alex I'm interested in the board design (though I don't understand what you mean by *prove a point*, so it would be kool if you explain). As mentioned in [the other question](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/582/), I wanted to know what other experienced people thought of the design.

Comment: No worries, I was just making sure it wasn't a `"rant disguised as a question: “______ sucks, am I right?”` (from [FAQ](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/faq#dontask))

Comment: Maybe a bit late, but everythgin you said. If it looks rubbish then it is rubbish. You can buy a cheap 5 Rand device and the PCB to a similar upmarket one. You will quickly see the difference. Missing links, some things not soldered properly, missing protection devices(to make it cheaper) , etc. A good PCB looks good, like the Rapsberry Pi (THe ones made at Sony in UK)- The PCB design, there are many ways to figure out if a pro made it or not, but generally PCB that are made in factories look good, either way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm an electronics professional and I understand what it takes to layout a PCB to meet a design goal and price. Placement is part of the PCB layout - seems fine to me but then I've been hanging around on the forum's to understand some of the constraints and all of the design goals. I have 4 Pi's, all of which look like they were manufactured with care, no poor trimming, no poor soldering.

Short answer to your question, in my opinion, is NO.

One wonders about your motives for asking the question.

Comment: am curious what you mean by motives

Comment: @Tshepang: It seems as if you're trying to get someone to say that the Pi has been poorly designed.

Comment: @Jivings you gotta forgive me if I sounded that way, but I did not mean it; I just wanted to hear what other people were thought

Comment: @Tshepang I forgive you :)